How to Disable Outgoing SSH for Users on Ubuntu Server While Allowing Incoming SSH Access?
Hello Ubuntu community,
I'm seeking guidance on how to implement a specific security measure on my Ubuntu server. I want to restrict all users from initiating outgoing SSH connections to external servers while retaining the ability for incoming SSH connections to the server.
Here's what I aim to achieve:
Users on the Ubuntu server should not be able to SSH into external servers.
However, I still need to SSH into the Ubuntu server from external locations.
Could someone provide me with step-by-step instructions or a recommended approach to implement this configuration? I'm particularly interested in utilizing firewall rules or any other appropriate methods to achieve this.
Your assistance is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Whether this is possible might depend on what you mean by "should not be able to SSH into external servers". If you're thinking of blocking outgoing connections to port 22, there are many servers which use other ports for SSH (including some that use port 443, such as ... GitHub itself!)

@muru thanks for response,I know it is strange but is it possible to deactive ssh command?

ssh initiates outgoing SSH sessions, sshd handles incoming SSH.  The easy way to stop users from SSHing out is: sudo chmod g-rwx,o-rwx $(type -p ssh). This will still allow root to use seh in the outgoing direction.

What @waltinator suggested, but note that your permission change might be lost when the openssh-client package gets updated, so using ACLs might be better.
